# How to create new SSDT Analysis Services Tabular Project from deployment files?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas-tabular

I have three deployment SSAS Tabular model files:

- Model.asdatabase
- Model.deploymentoptions
- Model.deploymenttargets

and I want to open this model in a new Tabular project in SSDT.
Is there a way to somehow import these files into a SSDT project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the [Analysis Services Deployment Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174817.aspx) and choose the asdatabase file. Deploy a new database to the SSAS server. Then in Visual Studio do File... New Project... Business Intelligence... SSAS... Import from Server (Tabular).

Comment: Hi, you know, I found this way quite quickly but it just does not feel like the shortest one. I will accept your answer as the best if there will be no others